# Is a Firebase Notification Received for a web app running on a mobile browser in the background?

Tags: firebase, web-applications, firebase-cloud-messaging, mobile-browser

The natural way to use Firebase on mobile is using Android or iOS.

However, I'm in this situation where a client who developed a web app wants to receive push notifications when:

1. The web app runs on a mobile browser
2. The mobile browser app is in background

**Is that possible?**

**Note**: According to [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive), client web apps can receive push notifications when they are in background, but I'm not sure if that extends to web apps running on a mobile browser in background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can receive push notifications on your mobile even when your browser is not open, but you need to enable it by pressing *Allow* when prompted, as below.

[image]